# Partial derivatives of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$

First question: How to find $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$? I have figured out this using definition - Both are $0$.

My next question is: How to show that $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ are the only directional derivative that exist at $(0,0)$?

Again, using definition, let the direction be $\mathbf{v}=(u,v)$. $\nabla_\mathbf{v}f(0,0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(f(hu,hv)-f(0,0))/h = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h\sqrt{|uv|} = 0$.

What's wrong with my argument?

Comment: Have you tried using the definition? What are you having problems with?

Comment: Oh. I got it. Using definition, I got both partial derivatives are $0$. Let me ask my next question instead.

Comment: If you don't know how to solve a problem, work from the definitions. Edit fast before the MSE police sees this.

Comment: Again: have you tried using the definition?

Comment: Tried now. But I get all directional derivatives exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miscomputed something.

Note that, given $\mathbf v=(u,v)$,
$$\begin{align}
\nabla_\mathbf{v}f(0,0) &= \lim \limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\dfrac{f(hu,hv)-f(0,0)}{h}\right)\\
&= \lim \limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left[\dfrac {\left(\left|h^2uv\right|\right)^{1/2}}{h}\right]\\ 
&= \lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac {\color{red}| h\color{red}|\sqrt{|uv|}}{h}\right).
\end{align}$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: I see my miscomputation. Got it. thx.

Comment: @user130916 You're welcome.

Comment: Is the given function continuous at (0,0)

Comment: @sabeelmsk Yes.